# Setting the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, winforms

Given the following code, how is that I receive an ArguementOutOfRangeException?

```
if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

This code is in my forms Load event. I know the combo box has items in it, but yet I cannot set the selected index. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex%28VS.80%29.aspx) says that the ArguementOutOfRangeException is thrown if the specified index is less than or equal to -2, or if it is greater than or equal to the number of items in the combobox.

The quick test app I just wrote doesn't exhibit the same problem - what could be going on?

Comment: I think more code is required.  It's clear that if you created a test application with the same code and it didn't produce the problem, other code is responsible.

Comment: make sure your combo is binding to data source or you have inserted the ListItem before calling this code and  it will return -1 if no item is selected

Comment: maybe it is not rendered yet? Can you do this call under a button instead under the form load.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't I quite the idiot. The selected index changed event was firing, and in that code a different combobox had it's selectedIndex set to 0 - however with certain data it wasn't being populated, and there was no basic error checking before setting the selectedIndex.

Sigh.